# SQL subquery and join performance issue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2000

```
       `select * from DETAIL a
        where a.BUILD > GETDATE() - 90 s
        and (a.IN + a.Rt) NOT IN (SELECT Sample_IN + Rt FROM  SUMMARY)                  
        and (a.Rt + a.Err) IN 
       (SELECT Rt + Err 
        FROM SUMMARY 
        where (sample_in + rt + err) NOT IN 
       (SELECT in + rt + err FROM DETAIL)) 
        group by a.rt, a.plant, a.in, a.build`
```

This query is showing performance issues , it runs faster in sql2000 server , but exhibits poor performance in sql2008R2. The tables in both the ennvironment have same properties(column datatypes and indexes) . I guess there is some propablity  in the "+" operator for select clause. can anyone help me ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with sqlserver, so I do not know if you can do it, but why not use (a.in,a.Rt) not in (select sample_IN,Rt from SUMMARY)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indexes do not work when you concatenate fields. You can create columns in your table that will already combine those fields, and create an index on those fields. This will improve your performances.

Also, note that this query will run faster and use your current indexes (forgive me for typos, you did not include tables definition) :

```
select * 
  from DETAIL a
 where a.BUILD > DateAdd( Day, -90, GetDate() )
   and not exists ( select null 
                      from SUMMARY 
                     where SUMMARY.Sample_IN = a.IN and SUMMARY.Rt  = a.Rt )
   and exists ( select null
                 from SUMMARY 
                where not exists ( select null
                                     from DETAIL 
                                    where DETAIL.in = SUMMARY.Sample_IN 
                                      and DETAIL.Rt = SUMMARY.Rt 
                                      and DETAIL.Err = SUMMARY.Err)
                  and a.Rt = SUMMARY.Rt
                  and a.Err = SUMMARY.Err ) 
group by a.rt, a.plant, a.in, a.build
```

Comment: Hello @dominic thanks for the suggestion . The above query runs fine in sql2000 server but issue is in sql2008 server, do you have any idea about this ??  the concatenated columns are of character type.. the table in the two servers are of same properties .

Answer (score 0):

```
    select * from DETAIL a 
    left outer join SUMMARY sm1
      on a.IN = sm1.Sample_IN 
     and a.Rt = sm1.Rt 
    join SUMMARY sm2
      on a.Rt = sm2.Rt
     and a.Err = sm2.Err
    left outer join Detail d 
      on sm2.Sample_IN = d.in
     and sm2.rt = d.rt
     and sm2.err = d.err
    where a.BUILD > GETDATE() - 90 s
    and sm1.Rt is null 
    and d.in is null
    group by a.rt, a.plant, a.in, a.build
```

This is using joins.  For your problem with exists from Dominic Goulet will probably work better. +1

Comment: thanks @blam , my doubt is the same query runs fine in sql2000 but why does it fails in sql2008.. i think there might be a settings related issue.. can you guide me ?

Comment: Do you have the same indexes in SQL2008.   Compare the query plans and see what it different.

Comment: yeah same indexes on both the servers. still the issue persists

Comment: Did you compare the query plans?

Comment: no man , i kno oracle but sql is little different. i don kno how to infer from the graphical representation..

Comment: Then this is a training issue.  SO is for specific programming questions.

Comment: sql2000 uses indexes on individual columns when used in concatenated columns are used where as sql2008 doesnot do this,, do you have any idea  on this ???

Comment: i checked the execution plan. in sql2000 it uses hash join where as in sql2008 it uses merge join . does it have any effect ???

Comment: 7 comments ago I suggested you compare query plans.  You have an accepted answer.